# Is there a rising trend in Number Series

Tags: time-series, trend

I am trying to build a stock screening utility.

What  I am trying is to find if there is a rising trend in a time series of profit margins of a company. I know there can be dips in some years but I want to find if mathematically that overall there is a rising trend as well as towards the recent years there is higher margins as compared to previous years.

Is there any way we can find it mathematically?

```
        Profit Return
Year,Company A,Company B,Company C
2005,38.97,20.44,22.01
2006,22.4,20.59,20.63
2007,22.4,20.59,20.63
2008,21.56,22.01,23.87
2009,25,20,23.52
2010,25,22.38,18
2011,30,24.13,24.85
2012,32,25.43,27.47
2013,30,20,22
2014,35,27,20
```

Comment: One way to tackle such time series data is to use [General Additive Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model). For example, see: http://www.r-bloggers.com/identifying-periods-of-change-in-time-series-with-gams/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [correlation coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation), or more precisely significance tests based on them, as you want to find out, whether there is a significantly positive correlation between the profit margins and time.

To briefly address the possible choices of correlation coefficients:

- [Pearson’s r](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) regards your time series’ absolute values but makes some assumptions regardang the nature of the correlation, namely it should be linear. Therefore you need to have some a priori knowledge that the correlation is linear or at least approximately linear (or if you have some other knowledge regarding the general functional form of your time series, you can use this to transform your data).
- [Spearman’s ρ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman's_rank_correlation_coefficient) and [Kendall’s τ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient) are rank-based, i.e., they only regard the order of values and thus outliers do not have a huge impact and also no assumptions are made as to the correlation being linear. Whether this is what fits you hypothesis is something you have to decide.

As your time series seem to be comparably short, make sure that you use an implementation of these coefficients that does not use too strong approximations for small datasets.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I do not have the year (as X that is Time like 1,2,3,4 etc) for correlation computation. What I have is Profit Margin Time series only in order of Time (as Y).      Is there no way I can calculate Correlation using Profit Margin Time Series only with the assumption that the Time series is ordered Oldest to Newest Years?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just use 1, 2, 3, 4, … as your times. If you do not know that your time series is regularly sampled, this would be another argument for a rank-based correlation coefficient, as they only regard the order of times anyway: It does not make a difference, if your times are 0,1,2,3,4 or −4004, −1, 4, 2000, 200000.